# SubSonic3 Context.cs Issue

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

I have an issue when the Context.cs is generated.

I have followed the SubSonic3 setup for ActiveRecord, http://www.subsonicproject.com/docs/Using_ActiveRecord. I am using the AdeventureWorks sample database provided by MS.

This is one of many lines having the issue:
**DataProvider.Schema.Tables.Add(new StoreTable(DataProvider));**

This is the error I am receiving for all tables in the database:
The type or namespace name 'StoreTable' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I would appreciate any help resolving this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey Rich - make sure you use the "Structs.tt" file as well - I need to update the docs. The Structs generate the schema stuff you need.

Comment: Rob - Thanks, my issue has been resolved. BTW, I love SubSonic!